# Painting numbers used as markers in different colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to represent a dataset of dots, each dot having an x and y coordinate and a single-digit value, and each of the values should be represented by a particular color. What I managed to do is creating sth like that, which looks nice enough:

```
# x, y and digits are one-dimensional np.arrays of the same shape
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', c=digits)
#random colormap
plt.viridis()
```

Now I want to represent digits themselves instead of just colored dots. As I understand it, marker-argument cannot be an array so I decided that sth like that would work:

```
for i in range(len(digits)):
    plt.scatter(x[i], y[i], c=digits[i], marker=('${}$'.format(digits[i])))
```

Which almost did, but 'c=digits[i]' doesn't seem to work because a digit doesn't actually encode any particular color. I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that the first code works, because python somehow automatically understands that by c=digits I didn't mean any actual color but wanted to differentiate between two dots.

So the question is:
What is the easiest thing I can do in the second case to indicate the colors of the digits without stating them directly but using a default colormap? (ideally I would like to get sth identical to what first code does, but with digits instead of dots)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have found a solution, so in case sb has a similar question:

```
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('name_of_demanded_colormap', neededColorsNum).colors
for i in range(len(digits)):
    plt.scatter(x[i], y[i], \\
        c=np.array([cmap[digits[i]]]), \\
        marker=('${}$'.format(digits[i])))
```

Some "explanations":
 - cm is an object needed for gods know what reason;

- get_cmap is the method which creates the specified color map, which is unexpectedly not an array but another gods know what object;
- colors is the method of color map which finally creates sth to work with, a matrix with rows representing colors;
- the code is so natural, jupyter demands to make the color-row two-dimensional, because some misinterpretation possibility.

Whatever complaints, works as intended, so good enough.